# Trying to build Android app but got clang error

Tags: android, go, fyne

I want to start and just build and run Hello World app in my mobile. I've installed `NDK`, `clang-12`, `Fyne` and run

```
fyne package --os android --appID com.example.myapp
```

Got

```
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o /tmp/gomobile-work-791801243/lib/armeabi-v7a/libparts.so parts failed: exit status 2
# runtime/cgo
clang: error: no input files
```

The project's structure:

```
parts:
    - go.mod
    - Icon.png
    - main.go
```

If I run manually from project root (parts)

```
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o /tmp/gomobile-work-791801243/lib/armeabi-v7a/libparts.so parts
```

It creates .so file without any error. Seems like it's just about relative path, but how can I fix it?

Comment: You seem to be missing go.sum, can you run”go mod tidy” and try again?

Comment: @andy.xyz there's go.sum, this is not the reason

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling the fyne command in the correct directory? is the main.go the raw hello world from the documentation, or are there any new build tags or changes to the code?

Comment: You could try using fyne-cross as that has a known Android setup, so it would eliminate one possible area of issues

Answer (score 0):

You might have a broken development environment when trying to build for Android. Short of reinstalling it, I would recommend using [fyne-cross](https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne-cross) with either *docker* or *podman*.

Just install fyne-cross with:

```
go install github.com/fyne-io/fyne-cross@latest
```

Followed in your application directory by:

```
fyne-cross android
```

Answer (score 0):

Description:
Overarching algorithm to solve most general problems ( related to ndk ) on Linux

1. go to the ndk directory
2. look for "source.properties" file
3. open it to see the "Pkg.Revision"
4. open the terminal in the current ndk directory
5. execute the "pwd" command in the terminal to find the full path for your current ndk directory
6. execute "vim ~/.bashrc" and click "i" to be in insert mode
7. add the line "export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=the path you obtained in step 5/the ndk version number you obtained in step 3
8. click "exit button" on your keyboard to exit insert mode
9. type the following (:wq!) without brackets
10. click enter button to save and exit the file
11. in the terminal run the command "fyne package -os android -appID com.example.appName -icon Icon.png"
12. wait a little time to finally get the .apk file which is for android

For step 11 you have to have an image that is either .png or .jpeg in the main directory of the program and call it "Icon.png" or "Icon.jpeg" so that your program is compiled and use that Icon image as its icon on android.